# linking jsoncpp on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, jsoncpp

I try to use jsoncpp library with c++ on Ubuntu.
I compiled the code and built the library with scons.
Now I can compile a simple programme:

```
#include "json/json.h"
#include <json/value.h>
#include <json/writer.h>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I use this command to compile:

```
g++ test.cpp -usr/lib/libjson_linux-gcc-4.8_libmt
```

I conclude that the compiler knows where to find the library.
The problem comes when I declare a json object:

```
Json::Value root;
```

Then I have this error message:
undefined reference to « Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType) »

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: -L to point to library location, -l to link to a library

Comment: So -L/usr/lib -ljsoncpp

Comment: You say you build library with scons. Did you build jsoncpp library yourself. Maybe compiled does not know where to search your custom library

Comment: I did build the library myself and then I copied the file
libjson_linux-gcc-4.8_libmt in /usr/lib.
I tried with -L/usr/lib -ljsoncpp
And it works ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For **CodeBlocks (Ubuntu 14.04)**

I have faced same problem in my codeblocks IDE after installing `jsconcpp`. This is how I rectified my problem.

Got to `project>Build Options>linker settings` and in the `link libraries` add `jsconcpp` and click ok